# Velocity problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Beni and Gal compete in running on straight track AB, that distance is 50m.
They both started from point A on that track and run to point B.
Beni leaped first. Gal leaped one second after Beni and reached him in a distance of 10m from point A. 
When Gal arrived to point B he immediately ran back to point A, and met again Beni that was still running from point A.
The second meeting occurred 10 seconds after Beni leaped from point A. 
Their velocities hadn't changed. 
What was the distance from point B that they both met(in the second time)?

Comment: What have you tried?  Let Beni's speed in m/sec be $b$ and Gal's be $g$.  Can you write equations to translate the sentences?

Comment: Yes, my attempt: $bt=10$, $g(t-1)=10$ and $10b+10g=50$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first two equations reflect the first meeting correctly.  For the third, at the second meeting Beni has been running for $10$ seconds, but Gal has only been running for $9$.  The total distance covered is $100$m, as Beni has covered some of the track and Gal has covered all the track plus the part Beni has not covered.  So $10b+9g=100$  Now we have three equations in three unknowns.  Can you solve them?